Jfrog Artifactory - 7.46.11 's compatibility with RHEL 7.9
need to know if old version of jfrog Artifactory( 7.46.11) is compatible with RH 7.9, currently it is running in RHEL 7.5, Jfrog's site doesn't help
Similarly Jfrog Missioncontrol and xray are running in rhel 7.5, I do not have an option to raise a support ticket with jfrog with. looking for community/forum which helps
Jfrog's site only has compatibility info for their latest version of artifactory.

Yes, the old version of Artifactory 7.46.11 is compatible with RHEL 7.9. However, please be informed that RHEL 7.x - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.x (has reached End of Full Support in 2019).
In the future, if the Artifactory upgrade is being performed to the latest versions then we need to migrate to RHEL 8.x or higher.
For more information on Platform support, refer to this documentation.
